# SoftLayer S3 API Create new credential

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

for our requirements we need to be able create an addition credential, we found this option is available UI, would like to know if can be done through API?

I've noticed there is possible to create two credentials, is this restricted? If this is expected, how can I get all credentials and delete one of them?

Would like to get the way to do these tasks in API. Please support me

Answer (score 0):

### To get limit of credentials

The Object Storage S3 has a limit of 2 credentials by default, you can check with the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/20654699/getCredentialLimit

Method: Get
```

### To get credentials:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/20654699/getCredentials

Method: Get
```

### To create credential:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/20654699/credentialCreate

Method: Get
```

### To delete credential:

```
https:/$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/20654699/credentialDelete

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
        "id": 550123
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope it helps, let me know if you need further assistance